# Why is $f'(x) $ of $y=\sqrt{5x} \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Why is $f'(x) $ of $y=\sqrt{5x}  \neq 0$?

I would have worked it out like this:
$f(x) =\sqrt 5.\sqrt{x} \equiv 5^{1/2}.x^{1/2}$

so $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0.(1)\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)x^{-1/2}$

since there is a zero constant, everything becomes zero!

However, watching http://www.mathtutordvd.com/products/Calculus-1-Extra-Practice-with-Derivatives.cfm, the answer is:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt 5.\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)x^{-1/2}$

This method seemingly(understandably) takes $\sqrt 5 $ as the constant (a) in the $anx^{n-1}$

However, am I logically wrong in using the first method? Why?

Comment: Perhaps you failed to realize this: The derivative of a product is *not* the product of the derivatives.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Using the second option and the product rule suffices. Thanks.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: If the derivative of a function is $0$ everywhere, what can we say about the function? Does $\sqrt{5x}$ follow that description?

Comment: More appropriately, note you do not need the product rule; just the constant multiple rule: $(cf)'=c f'$.

Comment: The derivative of $k$ $f(x)$ is $k$ $f'(x)$ if $k$ is a constant

Answer (score 2):

As you note, we can easily use the power rule here: $$f(x) = ax^n \implies f'(x) = n\cdot ax^{n-1}$$
$$y = \sqrt 5x^{1/2} \implies y' = \frac 12\cdot \sqrt 5 x^{-1/2} \neq 0$$

If you want to use the *product rule*, please note that for $f(x) = ax^n,$   $f'(x)\neq (a)'(x^n)'$.  That is, if $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, it **does not follow** that $f'(x) = g'(x)h'(x)$.

When we have $f(x)$ equal to the product of two functions, $$f(x) = g(x)h(x)$$ then by the **product rule** $$f'(x) = g'(x)h(x) + g(x)h'(x)$$